# NetLogo - In-Cone radius

Tags: netlogo

```
ask turtles
  [ ask patches in-cone 3 60
      [ set pcolor red ] ]
```

The code above means to have a cone of radius 3 and angle of 60 degrees. But I want a radius in range of 5 to 10. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I imagine it would work to use `in-cone` first, then filter the results using `distance`. (`in-radius` would be no help here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set up a variable that will hold the radius's that you have asked for. Let's call this variable `vision`. So,

```
let vision
set vision 5 + (random 5)
```

and then you can substitute `vision` instead of the `3` in your code.

```
ask turtles in-cone vision 60 [
set pcolor red
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways you could do it.  These are adapted into the *Vision Cone Example* model that comes in the models library with NetLogo, so we're using slightly different distances (between 9 and 30) to make the effect visually obvious.  I'd recommend `method1`, but I'm including `method2` as it's useful if you have some alternate logic to apply to the patches that are too close.

```
to method1 
  ; use `distance` to filter those that are too close
  ; `myself` refers to the turtle doing the asking
  ask patches in-cone 30 60 with [distance myself >= 9] [
    set pcolor grey
  ]
end

to method2
  ; create a local variable to store the turtles that 
  ; will be too close.  `self` refers to the patch
  ; being asked
  let too-close patches in-cone 9 60
  ask patches in-cone 30 60 with [not member? self too-close] [
    set pcolor gray
  ]
  ; I could use the `too-close` agentset here and ask them
  ; to do something, also.
end
```